# How to receive email notifications of newly accepted papers in a specified set of journals?

Tags: publications, journals, email, tools, economics

Is there some way of arranging that I receive emails whenever selected academic economics journals of interest to me, perhaps published by different publishers, post online a newly accepted paper?

Comment: I posted this question in the economics site because, as far as I know, the answer to this question is very different from discipline to discipline. As far as I understand, computer scientists are, for example, in this respect much better organized than economists.

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard of that. But you can setup an alert on Google scholar and get notifications when publications appear that match your search query or keywords.

Answer (score 4):

Most journal offer an email alert service for new issues/accepted papers. A couple of examples :

- https://www.aeaweb.org/notify/
- http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1111/%28ISSN%291468-0262 (see "Get new content alert")
- http://www.journals.elsevier.com/journal-of-economic-theory/ (see "Stay up to date")

Comment: All of ACM.org offers RSS feeds, which you can instrument with IFTTT

Answer (score 2):

Some publishers have a page introducing the ways by which their readers can be informed whenever a new issue of the journal is published, or a new paper is published in a journal. You should seek each journal for such email subscriptions.

Also, some websites of the journals provide [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) links for their users. You can copy the RSS link (news feed) of the journal you want to read in your RSS reader software or related online account. Every time an update (may be a newly published paper or a new journal issue) is posted on the publisher's/ journal's website, you will receive it's news on your RSS account.

As an example, the following links are for email subscription and RSS news feature which is available in [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) for their readers.

- [To Subscribe to the E-Mail Alerting Service](http://arxiv.org/help/subscribe)
- [RSS news feeds for arXiv updates](http://arxiv.org/help/rss)